# Printing double digits from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, data-structures, nested, formatting

I'm having trouble printing out some values from nested dictionary. My nested dictionary looks like this:

```
player_statistics = {'Johny': {'Kills': '7', 'Assists': '11', 'Deaths': '14'},
                     'Alice': {'Kills': '5', 'Deaths': '7', 'Assists': '3'},
                     'Jim': {'Kills': '14', 'Deaths': '6', 'Assists': '9'}}
```

I'm supposed to print out each infromation type for each player like this:

```
Player statistics:

ALICE
Assists: 3
Deaths: 7
Kills: 5
------------
JIM
Assists: 9
Deaths: 6
Kills: 14
------------
JOHNY
Assists: 11
Deaths: 14
Kills: 7
------------
```

But for some reason I end up having a result like this, where double digits' second number goes to the next line:

```
Player statistics:

ALICE:
Assists: 3
Deaths: 7
Kills: 5
------------
JIM
Assists: 9
Deaths: 6
Kills: 1
4
------------
JOHNY
Assists: 1
1
Deaths: 1
4
Kills: 7
------------
```

Here is my code:

```
def main():

    player_statistics = {'Johny': {'Kills': '7', 'Assists': '11', 'Deaths': '14'},
                         'Alice': {'Kills': '5', 'Deaths': '7', 'Assists': '3'},
                         'Jim': {'Kills': '14', 'Deaths': '6', 'Assists': '9'}}
    
    print("Player statistics:")
    print()
    for player in sorted(player_statistics):
        print(player.upper())
        for stat_type in sorted(player_statistics[player]):
            print(stat_type, end=": ")
            for value in sorted(player_statistics[player][stat_type]):
                print(value)
        print("------------")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I believe the issue is caused by the formatting on the line 12. Why does it work like this, instead of just giving the full double-digit value to the end of the stat_type line? Also, how can I make it to work properly?

Comment: 'value' is of type str and you simply iterate through every character of this string, so every digit is printed on a different line

Comment: @ccre I tried to assing the value as integer like this: `value = int(value)` before printing it but it still resulted in the same aftermath? Something wrong with my coding program or am I just assigning it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```py
for stat_type in sorted(player_statistics[player]):
    print(stat_type, end=": ")
    for value in sorted(player_statistics[player][stat_type]):
        print(value)
```

It should be something like this:

```py
for stat_type in sorted(player_statistics[player]):
    print(f"{stat_type}: {player_statistics[player][stat_type]}")
```